# ¿Como consumo un ws con WSDL para poder enviar un parametro y que me retorne un fichero xml?

Tags: c#, xml, webservice, wsdl

Actualmente me dan un archivo wsdl en una ruta de internet que seria de la siguiente forma:

```
https://xxxxxx.xx.com/xxxx.xx?WSDL
```

Y cuando lo recibo lo único que me nada es la estructura del WSDL, como se hace para que yo le pueda mandar un valor que en este caso es uno y me retorne el fichero xml.

Ya lo intente agregándolo como web reference e intentando acceder de la siguiente forma:

```
    santecmxdes.execute hola = new santecmxdes.execute();
    hola.modo = "1";
    var retorno = hola.ToString();
```

También lo intente de la siguiente forma:

```
    string NodoReturn = "<soapenv:Envelope><soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><get:Execute><modo>1</modo></get:Execute></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Header></soapenv:Envelope>";
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("xxxxxxx") as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxx", "xxxx");
    request.Timeout = 300000;
    request.ContentType = "application/xml";
    request.Accept = "application/xml";
    Encoding e = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream, e);
    requestWriter.Write(NodoReturn);
    requestWriter.Close();
    HttpWebResponse response;
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var encoding = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;
    using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
    {
        string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Pero la forma que esta aquí arriba solo me retorna la estructura del wsdl y yo requiero una respuesta en formato xml de data que es diferente.

Por lo que eh leido esa ruta debo meterla en la clase proxy para que me genere las herramientas necesarias para enviar data y recibir de la misma forma data, pero no se muy bien como se hace eso del proxy.

> Update

Estructura del WSDL:

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://www.service-now.com/GetTimeCardMode"><wsdl:types><xsd:schema elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://www.service-now.com/GetTimeCardMode"><xsd:element name="execute"><xsd:complexType><xsd:sequence><xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="modo" type="xsd:string"/></xsd:sequence></xsd:complexType></xsd:element><xsd:element name="executeResponse"><xsd:complexType><xsd:sequence><xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="status" type="xsd:string"/><xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="time_card" type="xsd:string"/></xsd:sequence></xsd:complexType></xsd:element></xsd:schema></wsdl:types><wsdl:message name="executeSoapIn"><wsdl:part name="GetTimeCardMode" element="tns:execute">
    </wsdl:part></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="executeSoapOut"><wsdl:part name="GetTimeCardMode" element="tns:executeResponse">
    </wsdl:part></wsdl:message><wsdl:portType name="ServiceNowSoap"><wsdl:operation name="execute"><wsdl:input message="tns:executeSoapIn">
    </wsdl:input><wsdl:output message="tns:executeSoapOut">
    </wsdl:output></wsdl:operation></wsdl:portType><wsdl:binding name="ServiceNowSoap" type="tns:ServiceNowSoap"><soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/><wsdl:operation name="execute"><soap:operation soapAction="http://www.service-now.com/GetTimeCardMode/execute" style="document"/><wsdl:input><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input><wsdl:output><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output></wsdl:operation></wsdl:binding><wsdl:service name="ServiceNow_GetTimeCardMode"><wsdl:port name="ServiceNowSoap" binding="tns:ServiceNowSoap"><soap:address location="https://santecmxdes.service-now.com/GetTimeCardMode.do?SOAP"/></wsdl:port></wsdl:service></wsdl:definitions>
```

Código de obtención del WSDL C#

```
  santecmxdes.execute hola = new santecmxdes.execute();
        hola.modo= "1";
        santecmxdes.ServiceNow_GetTimeCardMode hola2 = new santecmxdes.ServiceNow_GetTimeCardMode();
        NetworkCredential credencial =new NetworkCredential("xxxx", "xxx");
        hola2.Credentials= credencial;
        hola2.Timeout = 300000;
        santecmxdes.executeResponse response1 = new santecmxdes.executeResponse();
        response1 = hola2.execute(hola);
```

El código de arriba es para obtener mi xml de acuerdo al valor de la variable modo que debe estar en "1", al final la siguiente linea `hola2.execute(hola)` me devuelve null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes el `wsdl` no necesitas armar todo el mansaje `soap` puede crear una `Web Reference`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto creara el codigo de un proxy el cual instanciaras para invocar el servicio

Si tienes solo la opcion de `Service Reference` no ha problema, porque se puede ingresar a esta y despues cambiar usando la opcion `Advanced`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: oye ya actualice mi post, es que ya lo hice de la forma que dijiste agregando el wsdl como referencia web pero ahora segun la estructura del WSDL debo poner en el atributo mod un "1" y despues ponerlo en un execute que al final el resultado ira en un executeresponse, pero el execute me devuelve un null